# feature is site-scoped and cannot be added to the web sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, feature, ssom

Iam deploying solution to site scoped feature , and in feature activated event receiver iam writing the code to activate feature to all subsites but error is "feature is site-scoped and cannot be added to the web sharepoint 2010 "
and code is

```
using (SPSite osite = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite)
                    {
                        Guid featureGuid = new Guid(xxxxxxxxxxxxx);
                        foreach (SPWeb webs in osite.AllWebs)
                        {
                            webs.Features.Add(featureGuid);
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: It is correct the error. What does the feature do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site features (here `site` means "site collection", while `web` means root-site/sub-site) can only be activated at a site-collection level (i.e. from the root-site of a collection, under the "Site collection features" page).
Site features produce their effects on the entire site collection. For instance:

- If it contains a custom action, the custom action is visible in all sub-sites.
- If it contains a Web part, the Web part is provisioned in the site collection Web part galery (located at the root-level) and is then available for all sites in the collection.

Some artifacts cannot be scoped `site` (see list at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms454835(v=office.14).aspx)).

So, either your feature is `site` scoped, or it's `web` scoped. There's no point at all in trying to activate a `site` feature at a `web` level. And it's not your responsibility to activate a `site` feature on all sub-sites: intrinsically, the `site` feature impacts all sites (webs) of the collection.